# f2py. fortran subroutine arguments on multiple lines. "unknown_subroutine"

Tags: python, interface, fortran, subroutine, f2py

I am working on a python/fortran interface using f2py.
My fortran code has some subroutines whose list of arguments are longer than one line, so I have used the standard fortran rule to break a line, i.e.:

```
  SUBROUTINE mutation(it,pop,pm,pmg,typem,xmin,xmax,newfx,nbvar,
  $popsize,tip,nouvpop,nbnew)
```

When I try to build the python module with f2py, using the command :

```
f2py3 -c forFunct.f -m mga
```

I get this :

```
...
Block: unknown_subroutine
...
Constructing wrapper function "unknown_subroutine"...
      unknown_subroutine()
```

and eventually

```
error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-
prototypes -fPIC -I/tmp/tmp1tw75l/src.linux-x86_64-3.3 
-I/Produits/publics/x86_64.Linux.RH6/python/3.3.3/lib/python3.3/site-
packages/numpy/core/include -
I/Produits/publics/x86_64.Linux.RH6/python/3.3.3/include/python3.3m -c 
/tmp/tmp1tw75l/src.linux-x86_64-3.3/mgamodule.c -o 
/tmp/tmp1tw75l/tmp/tmp1tw75l/src.linux-x86_64-3.3/mgamodule.o" 
failed with exit status 1
```

Do you know any solution to this problem? I am sure that it comes from the multiple lines arguments, is it supported by f2py?

Thank you

Francesco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How exactly do you break the lines? It is not clear from your snippet, but it looks like it is wrong. If I do it in the *real* standard way, with positioning any character in the 6th column, it works.

```
1234567
      SUBROUTINE mutation(it,pop,pm,pmg,typem,xmin,xmax,newfx,nbvar,
     $    popsize,tip,nouvpop,nbnew)
      END
```

Comment: As mostly a python dev... wow. The 1900s must have been a tough time. Thank you for this bit of arcane knowledge!